# Persian Thesis Template

Tags: templates, thesis, xepersian, persian

Is there any M.Sc. Thesis LaTeX template available ?
It would be nice if it is according to rules of Sharif University in writing Thesis!

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a Persian LaTeX Thesis template

Comment: No, did you ask for a template at the university?

Comment: No, I didn't. But If there was, it was available online.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Please take a look at item B:Guides on Writing Thesis from http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~amehrabi/writing.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. You can find a template according to "Sharif University of Technology" rules in `Parsilatex` website.

See [here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=86:1389-01-03-00-05-55&catid=41:1388-06-28-10-27-50&Itemid=74) and [here](http://www.parsilatex.com/forum/SMF/index.php?topic=2023.msg14161) (courtesy of M. Sharifitabar). Support is also available through [`parsilatex forum`](http://www.parsilatex.com/forum/SMF/index.php).